# How do I avoid matching a longer string in favor of shorter sub-string?

Tags: python, regex

I have have the following regex intended to extract the number of people going to an event based on social media data:

I'm new to regular expressions but I've tried to use {} to limit the number of matching characters.

```
([0-9]+)?(,)?[0-9]+(\s*(\.|,)\s*[0-9])?\s*(k|K)?\s*(P|p).*e\s*(G|g).*g
```

The problem is that it not only matches this "60 people going" but also this "184 people interested 20 people going".

In the first case it gives me the desired value (i.e. 60) but in the second case I'm getting 184 rather than 20.

---

Example 1:

`"United Muslims of America shared their event. \nSponsored B \nIf you also think that there should only be peace, come with us on Juney 3 \nand let's make it happen. \nStop warl Stop killing the innocent! \nsrop \nKiLLiNG \nTHE iNNOCENT \nJUN \nLike \nMake peacei not war! \nSat PM EDT The White House Washington, \n184 people interested 20 people going \nComment \nInterested \n"`

Example 2:

`"BM shared their event. \nSponsored \nWe're proud to announce an initiative focused on providing free legal \neducation to empower our people and strengthen our community. \nWe believe that having these legal workshops on a monthly basis will prove \nto be beneficial in a tangible way for our community \nMeet you at \nLEGAL \nNIGHT A \nCharlotte, NC \nFREE LEGAL INFO FOR COMMUNITY \nJANUARY, 28, 5 PM \nJAN \n28 \nLegal Night at \nSat 5 PM \n95 people interested 18 people going \nCharlotte \n* Interested \n19 Reactions \nLike Comment \n"`

Comment: Data samples are crucial for your question to get answered.

Comment: Both `.*` at the end will match anything when your sentence ends with 'g' and contains an other one before.

Comment: Example 2: 
"BM shared their event. \nSponsored \nWe're proud to announce an initiative focused on providing free legal \neducation to empower our people and strengthen our community. \nWe believe that having these legal workshops on a monthly basis will prove \nto be beneficial in a tangible way for our community \nMeet you at \nLEGAL \nNIGHT A \nCharlotte, NC \nFREE LEGAL INFO FOR COMMUNITY \nJANUARY, 28, 5 PM \nJAN \n28 \nLegal Night at \nSat 5 PM \n95 people interested 18 people going \nCharlotte \n* Interested \n19 Reactions \nLike Comment \n",

Comment: Why not simplify it a bit to `\b\d+ [pP]\w+e [Gg]\w+g\b` https://regex101.com/r/Xpcq2Y/1 and perhaps match `[Gg]oing` and `[Pp]eople`. Are there other possible matches?

Comment: Fourth bird - I think you got it!  I've split it by line in the pdf to help avoid false matches.  I'm very new to this and I appreciate everyone's help.  Thierry and Giova - thank you!  How do I mark this as solved?

Comment: An alternative: one or more numbers followed by one or more characters that are not numbers followed by "going" (capitalized or not) - `([0-9]+)[^0-9]+[gG]oing` - It will. mistakenly. match something like "19 heard about it but none are going"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match digits followed by people going, you can omit adding optional parts using `?` in between as it is matching too much.

Some parts in your pattern can be optimized. Assuming you are not using the captured groups separately in the code and want a match only:

- `(P|p)` can be written as `[pP]` using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `([0-9]+)?` can be written as `[0-9]*`
- `(G|g).*g` will match G or g until the last occurrence of g. You might update that to `[Gg]\S*g` using `\S` to match a non whitespace char.

For example

```
 \b[0-9]+ [Pp]eople [Gg]oing\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gNYY9x/1)